# ios create 'readmore'. Let superview be dependent of subview

Tags: ios, resize, subview, superview, tableheader

gaaah designing in ios gives me headache!!
So please, help me out and maby explain to me how one should think trying to come up with the solution.

I have:

[image: UITableView with its header]

- As you can see the UITextField has its frame being set in storyboard to be smaller than its actual content.
- Everything above the prototypecell is within a UIView that is set to be tableHeader programatically.

I want to:

Press the read more btn so that the UITextField get its actual size. No problem, I can do that with getting the contentSize programmatically. It works but it ofc overflows the tableHeader

So I thought, good. Then all I have to do is set the tableHeader to be the size of the 'new' calculated height of UITextField + height of the 2 UIImageViews.

But nope. it only resizes to the existing height set in storyboard insted. In other word, it does one or the other.
And using autolayout it totally breaks but not giving me any errors about constraints.

This seems so easy wich makes me feel so stupid haha

this is what I have i code

```
- (IBAction)toggleReadMore:(id)sender{

_toggleReadMoreBtn.hidden = YES;

CGRect textFrame = _cityDescription.frame;

_cityDescription.frame = textFrame;

CGRect tableHeaderViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.width, _cityDescription.contentSize.height + 218.0f ); //textFrame.size.height
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = tableHeaderViewFrame;

    textFrame.size.height = _cityDescription.contentSize.height;
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.viewForTableHeader];
```

please, guide me how to think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ScrrenShot indicating constraints]

```
 - (IBAction)readMoreBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
     {
         NSLog(@"Read more Btn Clicked");

         NSString *stringToBeDisplayed = @"Any Text Here";

         CGSize textSize=[stringToBeDisplayed sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30]
                                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(270, 500)
                                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

         NSLog(@"textSize = %@",NSStringFromCGSize(textSize));

        [self.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.textView.frame.origin.x,self.textView.frame.origin.y, textSize.width, textSize.height)];

        NSLog(@"self.textView.frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.textView.frame));

        [self.textView setText:stringToBeDisplayed];
        [self.headerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.headerView.frame.origin.x,self.headerView.frame.origin.y, 320, dynamicHeightCalculatedAfterTextSize)];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
```

Comment: dynamicHeightCalculatedAfterTextSize ? how do I set this one depended on content from db and textSize?

and I forgot to tell that I have the textView in a UIView of its own that needs to resize together with the textView.
I try to do
    `[self.textSuperView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.textView.frame.origin.x,self.textView.frame.origin.y, textSize.width, textSize.height)];`

But nothing happens.

Comment: Suppose if the Height of the HeaderView is 100 excluding (without) textview . Then dynamicHeightCalculatedAfterTextSize will be -dynamicHeightCalculatedAfterTextSize=100+textSize.height

Comment: change the SuperClass of your UIView to UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Comment: but I also have dynamic text comming from db

Comment: I have updated my answer above , now any text could be passed to the method . Since you are fetching dynamic text from database , pass the fetched text in place of "stringToBeDisplayed" in the code i provided above

Comment: finally I am getting somewhere, tnx m8 :))

 But I have to click the button twice. First time it sets the hight of the textView, second time it actually sets the text. why is this?

+ I had to add the `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.viewForTableHeader];`

Comment: Check whether are you getting the right string (value) from the database when you first click the button because if it is resizing the  textview then it must be setting the text . Check the value of string by NSLog before setting it on to the textview . Also make a confirmation that you are reloading the table soon after you are resizing the textview .